# AWSがホスティングしている、シンプルにIPアドレスだけを教えてくれるWebサイトのURLってなんでしたっけ？

Tags: aws, network

AWSのドキュメントで見たような覚えがあるのですが、IPアドレスだけを教えてくれるシンプルなWebサイトってありませんでしたっけ？

https://checkip.org などの超シンプル版で、本当にHTMLの中にIPアドレスしか入っていないサイトです。

検索しようにも類似サイトか関係ないAWSドキュメントしか出てこず、弱っております。
URLをお持ちの方、教えていただけないでしょうか？

または、類似サイトでも結構です（信頼できる運営元による、HTTPの問い合わせでこちらのIP「だけ」を教えてくれるサイト）（https://ipinfo.io などはIP以外の情報が多いので除外）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://checkip.amazonaws.com/

では、ないでしょうか。

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/batch/latest/userguide/get-set-up-for-aws-batch.html

に説明が掲載されているようです。